List<Character> to nodelist in java
How to convert List to nodelist in java can any one add the snippet
I tried to convert but it gave me error. Cannot cast arraylist to nodelist
I tried to search alot but didn't found any relevant solution.can anyone help on this

Please post the code you used

By the way, the char type and its wrapper class Character have been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5. As a 16-bit value, char is physically incapable of representing most characters. To work with individual characters, use Unicode code point integer numbers.

In Java, a NodeList is an interface provided by the Document Object Model (DOM) API. It is typically used to represent a collection of nodes obtained from methods like getElementsByTagName in the Document interface.
Unfortunately, you cannot directly cast an ArrayList to a NodeList because they are not part of the same class hierarchy. However, you can create a custom class that implements the NodeList interface and takes a List as an argument. Here’s a simple example:
import java.util.List;
public class CustomNodeList implements NodeList {
private final List nodes;
public CustomNodeList(List<Node> nodes) {
    this.nodes = nodes;
}

@Override
public Node item(int index) {
    return nodes.get(index);
}

@Override
public int getLength() {
    return nodes.size();
}

}
You can use this CustomNodeList class like this:
List yourList = ... // your list of Nodes
NodeList nodeList = new CustomNodeList(yourList);
